# SvelteKit or vite hot module reload breaks global scss

Tags: vite, sveltekit

When I `npm run dev` my SvelteKit / vite app locally, after a minute or so, a full hot module reload is triggered which leads to break my design.

Stacktrace example:

> 23:09:37 [vite] page reload .svelte-kit/generated/nodes/8.js
> 23:09:37 [vite] hmr update /.svelte-kit/generated/root.svelte
> 23:09:37 [vite] page reload .svelte-kit/generated/server-internal.js
> 23:09:37 [vite] page reload src/declarations/cmc/cmc.factory.did.js
> 23:09:37 [vite] hmr update /src/frontend/src/lib/components/guards/IdentityGuard.svelte

etc.

I am not sure is the issue is linked to the fact that my global style is not correctly reloaded (I'm using sass) or the fact that weirdly some raw script Svelte components are injected into style tag in the dom

e.g. I find following tag in the dom

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css" data-vite-dev-id="/Use...CollectionEdit.svelte?svelte&amp;type=style&amp;lang.css">
      ><script lang="ts">
    import type { PermissionText } from '$lib/constants/rules.constants';
        etc.
    </script>
  </style>
```

Another thing that is weird to me is that vite often detects changes in `tsconfig.json` and triggers new build even though the file has not changed in weeks

```
23:09:37 [vite] changed tsconfig file detected: /Users/.../admin/tsconfig.json - Clearing cache and forcing full-reload to ensure TypeScript is compiled with updated config values.
```

Any clue or idea what I can track to solve this issue?

Comment: You wouldn't by any chance happen to be using any sort of new preprocessor, would you? In my case I only started seeing this issue when I started using svelte-preprocess-cssmodules which also happens to have an invalid/inconsistent typescript peer dependency. Just asking in case this rings any bells for you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The only preprocessing I use is postcss along with autoprefixer. Interestingly, the problem has resolved itself recently. Although I haven't pinpointed the exact root cause, my current theory is that the issue might be related to the local backend server I'm running. It could be generating files or events at intervals that trigger the frontend server to reload. Not sure how but that's my current speculative theory.

Comment: Must admit, I was asking for selfish reasons to help me debug as well! For what it's worth, that helped me also narrow down some other unexpected behavior on my end to PhpStorm. Now I'm thinking it's some kind of interplay between inconsistent/invalid TypeScript versions between dependencies (e.g. TS 5.x in Svelte and TS 4.x in svelte-preprocess-cssmodules) combined with my IDE which is also hooking into TypeScript somehow. I was able to confirm by closing the IDE, or when open, disabling TypeScript language service. So... might boil down to that? Inconsistent TS versions in dependencies?

Comment: Not sure about TypeScript but, I am using a Jetbrains editor as well. More precisely Webstorm.

Comment: Closing the loop here: I resolved _my_ issue; turned out I had **>110k** files and a very inefficient `server.watch.ignored` array in my Vite config. Probably was a race condition (hence the unpredictability) that didn't occur until after I started adding more plugins to my Vite/Svelte setup. After tuning the ignore list, the problem went away entirely for me.

Comment: Great to hear you found the solution and thanks for the share! Might be useful for me someday too.

Answer (score 2):

Alright solved it or at least find a workaround. The issue seems to have been linked to the fact that my Mac triggers incorrect refresh through `fsEvents`. Even tough there are no changes on the local file system, it requests full reload after 1-2 min. Disabling fsEvents in the `vite.config.ts` prevents this to happen and per extension, avoid the problem.

```
server: {
  watch: {
    useFsEvents: false
  },
}
```

Why sass is not intepreted on full reload is to me unclear but, at least there is no more issue and hmr still works.

Comment: Thank you for your detective work David, it just helped me out a lot. In my situation, hammering the Vite dev server with Playwright tests would randomly (but reliably) cause the server to crash, as it would think that tsconfig had changed (along with vite config and .env.local) which led to it crashing. Turning off fsEvents seems to have solved it perfectly so far!